# Update failed with Could not load triggers. The error was Uncaught You must specify a key using Parse.initialize

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

I'm New to parse cloud code and i try to alert a test code but i come up with the above issue while trying to parse deploy,  Here is my code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {

    response.success("Hello world!");
});

Parse.Cloud.run('hello', {}, {
    success: function(result) {
    // result is 'Hello world!'
    },
    error: function(error) {
    }
});
```

I placed this code inside cloud/main.js. If i need to initialize parse.initialize where i can add this code? please help . Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call **run** method directly in main.js.

You have to make one more Cloud Function then call it inside that. Try this -

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
    response.success("Hello world!");
});

Parse.Cloud.define("executeHello", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.run('hello', {}, {
        success: function(){},
        error: function(){}
    });
});
```